# Locale number formatting issue windows 2008

Tags: windows, localization

On a project we have multiple servers running windows 2008. The servers are using the Russian locale. We have several programs that use floating point numbers but the fractional part of the number on SOME servers is getting truncated.

Through the regional settings each machine has:
Locale: Russian
Current Location: United States
Decimal Symbol: . (period)

I've tried distributing the changes through "Copy Settings" and even though the procedure works it seems like the settings aren't actually being propagated.

So next I went into the registry. There is a key called "sDecimal" and in all cases on all servers the value in the key is '.'

There is no difference that I can find between the servers that DO have correct decimal formatting and DO NOT.

Any advice on where I can look for a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Floating point number aren't exact and can be truncated sometimes.  This happens all the time in applications like SQL Server.  The application should be changed to use exact data types like int, numeric, etc.